# Creating referenced Instance of a prefab

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create an enemy spawner that will spawn a new enemy drone at a fixed interval. However, whenever I try to create a new instance while holding a reference to it, the previous instance is destroyed, creating errors.

This does not work

```
        void SpawnDrone()
    {
        GameObject newDrone;
        newDrone = (GameObject)Instantiate(drone, enemies.transform);
        newDrone.transform.position = gameObject.transform.position + new Vector3(0,0,5);

        Invoke("SpawnDrone", coolDown);
    }
```

While this does for some reason

```
    void SpawnDrone()
    {
        Instantiate(drone, enemies.transform);

        Invoke("SpawnDrone", coolDown);
    }
```

However, I need a reference to the drone when creating it.

This is the code in Start that Drone inherits that should be saving a reference to it in my list of game objects "scope"

```
    protected virtual void Start()
    {
        //Make sure that any GameEntity has a CollisionBox
        gameObject.GetComponent<CollisionBox>();

        //Add to Scope
        CollManager.Instance.scope.Add(gameObject);
    }
```

After a new Drone is created, Scope is left with a missing reference where the previous Drone was

Comment: How do you mean destroyed? Is the gameObject of the instance being destroyed? Or do you just lose the reference? Btw, as far as I can tell, and provided the function above is as-is, the variable where you store the reference (newDrone) only lives for the lifetime of the SpawnDrone function. You have to store it as a member variable of the MonoBehaviour for the reference to be accessible elsewhere or even in the next iteration of the function call (that is if you plan on doing anything to it.

Comment: @NPatch The Start() Method of a component on Drone adds it to a "scope" list of GameObjects in my GameManager. This is working fine, but when my DroneSpawner spawns a new instance, the reference in "scope" becomes a Missing Reference.

Comment: I think, a little more code would be nice. What type is `drone` here? How does your described `Start` look like and maybe also the part of the game manager and `DroneSpawner` that tries to access stuff. Because objects that are instantiated are usually not destroyed, because their variable goes out of scope.

Comment: On its own, instantiating a prefab does nothing to destroy others. It can just as well be code on your prefab that destroys the gameobject from a different point. Or you maybe doing something in DroneSpawner or whichever script tries to access the drone references and do sth with them, that overwrites or destroys the gameobject. Assuming the missing ref is from gameobject destruction that is, have you actually checked that the gameobject in the scene is destroyed? If not, make sure to add sth to their names, like spawn index and check again.
Agreed with Max, there's not enough code to go on.

Comment: @NPatch Added Start code and elaborated on the error. Unfortunately I don't know how much more I can elaborate on this without just posting my entire project.

Comment: 1) ```gameObject.GetComponent<CollisionBox>();``` This does nothing. If you're concerned about it, use RequiredComponent on the Drone MonoBehaviour and the CollisionBox gets added by default (although any values will be defaults or whatever you set as default values), but the component itself will be there for sure.
2) This is still too little code to glean anything. For starters, do you call Destroy on these at all? If so, check if they get destroyed somehow. If you call destroy on them anywhere, put a breakpoint and check the callstack to see where and why they are destroyed.

Comment: @NPatch destroy is never called anywhere, except within a method which explicitly removes it from scope before destroying it. How would I correctly debug this to figure out why the reference in the list is disappearing?

Comment: Use the debugger again and place a breakpoint on that function that removes explicitly. Other than that, add a method that will do the scope.Add and place a breakpoint there and step through things. Using watch on the scope list and looking at the callstack will tell you what you need to know. Instantiate is not your problem, as you do the same call in both working and non-working cases. You still do instantiate using the ```drone``` prefab and making it a child of enemies GameObject. Whatever the case, the Missing Ref points to destruction.